# "Text has zero width" error after reinitializing Pygame display?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a project in Pygame 1.9.2 where I reinitialize the display multiple times, and draw text to the display surface.  It works fine until I close the Pygame display and re-initialize it again.

It follows a structure like this:

```
from pygame import *
init() # this is pygame.init()
running = True
while running:
    display.set_mode((800,600))
    visible = True
    textFont = font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 12)
    while visible:
        for evt in event.get():
            if evt.type == QUIT:
                visible = False
            if evt.type == KEYDOWN:
                if evt.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    visible = running = False
        textPic = textFont.render("Hello world!", True, (255,255,255))
        display.get_surface().blit(textPic, (0,0))
        display.flip()
    quit()
```

This program works until the display is closed for the first time and then reinitialized, after which I receive the following error when trying to use `textFont.render`:

```
pygame.error: Text has zero width
```

I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out what's wrong... I know that `"Hello world!"` has a width greater than zero.  How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `pygame.quit()` was called before the program was finished.  This causes *every* Pygame module (e.g. `pygame.font`) to be uninitialized.

Instead of relying on `pygame.quit` to close the Pygame display, use `pygame.display.quit` at the end of every `while running` loop.  Then put `pygame.quit` at the very end of the script to unload the rest of the modules after they're done being used.

(Calling `pygame.init()` again before rendering text won't fix this issue either, because it causes the Pygame display to stop responding.  (This might be a bug with Pygame 1.9.2)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that worked for me: just delete the font element before calling `pygame.display.quit()`, ie just `del font` every time you're done using it.

The font element is the one you created using the command:

```
font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 12)
```

but that I personally create using `pygame.font.Font(None, font_size)`