# Displaying an integer as text in pygame

Tags: string, python-2.7, text, integer, pygame

In pygame I am trying to print the text '10 x 10'. The 10 is stored as an integer in sizeOfGrid variable. My current code is:

```
text = font.render((str(sizeOfGrid),'x',str(sizeOfGrid)), 1, (10, 10, 10))
textpos = (32,210)
screenDisplay.blit
```

When I run the program it returns the error `exceptions.TypeError: text must be string or unicode`. I don't understand this error or what is wrong as I have converted the 10 into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `font.render` must be of the datatype string or unicode. You probably just need to change that. Instead of `(str(sizeOfGrid),'x',str(sizeOfGrid)` you may write something like
`"%d x %d" % tuple([sizeOfGrid]*2)`.

The `"%d x %d"` part is the string format, where we ask for two digit arguments. With an tuple sample `(4, 4)` this would give us the string `"4 x 4"`.

To add arguments to the string, we use modulo followed by the arguments, that is `% tuple([sizeOfGrid]*2)` where `[sizeofGrid]*2` is `[10, 10]` and `tuple([sizeOfGrid]*2)` is `(10, 10)`, which happen to be our two digit arguments. You can use it like this:

```
text = font.render("%d x %d" % tuple([sizeOfGrid]*2), 1, (10, 10, 10))
```

Comment: I tried this method and it worked the first time I ran it, but every other time it has caused an error in another part of my code and caused pyscripter to crash. The code that gives an error is the first line of `text = font.render("Size of the grid:", 1, (10, 10, 10))
    textpos = (35,165)
    screenDisplay.blit(text, textpos)`  and it returns the error 'pygame.error: Text has zero width'

Comment: Perfect! The zero-text-width error is a totally different one that has to do with pygame's modules. One solution is to quit the display (NOT pygame) using `pygame.display.quit` instead of `pygame.quit`, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850868/text-has-zero-width-error-after-reinitializing-pygame-display).

Comment: Glad I could help! Please, mark the problem as solved if you are satisfied with any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this

```
screenDisplay.blit(font.render("{0}x{0}".format(sizeOfGrid), True, (10, 10, 10)), (32, 210))
```

`font.render` expects first arguement a string, you are providing a tuple.

note:I used `{0}x{0}` since both values are sizeOfGrid.