# pygame.error: Text has zero width; what's a better way to make it work?

Tags: python, oop, text, pygame

I am trying to write an entirely GUI-based text adventure (there are boxes that display text as well as buttons that you can click on to move and attack). I am having a little trouble displaying my boxes 
The following are the offending lines of code:

The relevant variable from the import in the next file:

```
textWhite = (240, 234, 214)
```

Where the error is happening

```
from globalvars import *
import pygame

class AbstractBanner:
    def __init__(self, centerX, centerY, width, height, color):
        self.leftX = centerX - width//2
        self.topY = centerY - height//2
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((scrW, scrH))

class Banner(AbstractBanner):
    def __init__(self, centerX, centerY, width, height, color, text, textSize):
        super().__init__(centerX, centerY, width, height, color)
        self.text = text
        self.textObject = pygame.font.SysFont("arial.ttf", textSize)
    def display(self):
        surface = self.textObject.render(self.text, True, textWhite)
        rect = surface.get_rect()
        rect.center = (self.leftX, self.topY)
        self.gameDisplay.blit(surface, rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.gameDisplay, self.color, (self.leftX, self.topY, self.width, self.height))
```

A truncated version of where the above code is executed (sans the game loop):

```
class screenDisplay():
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = "TITLE_SCREEN"
        self.states = ["TITLE_SCREEN", "MAIN_GAME", "COMBAT", "CUTSCENE"]
        if self.state == self.states[0]:
            self.showTitleScreen()
def showTitleScreen(self):
        #Background
        background = Banner(scrW//2, scrH//2, scrW, scrH, avocado, "  ", 2)
        background.display()
```

And here, in a fourth .py file, is the game loop that executes the above:

```
import pygame
import time
from screenDisplay import screenDisplay
import globalvars

# pylint: disable=no-member 
pygame.init() 
# pylint: enable=no-member
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
showGame = screenDisplay()

while not globalvars.gameIsDone:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # pylint: disable=no-member 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
            pygame.quit() 
            # pylint: enable=no-member
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850868/text-has-zero-width-error-after-reinitializing-pygame-display) question on SO, but I do not know where I should put the `del` line or even what I should be deleting. If the solution involves putting those two lines in the same file, are there any alternatives?

EDIT: Oh, and most important of all, here is the error!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Robertson\Desktop\Personal Projects\pytextrpg\gameLauncher.py", line 9, in <module>
    showGame = screenDisplay()
  File "c:\Users\Robertson\Desktop\Personal Projects\pytextrpg\screenDisplay.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.showTitleScreen()
  File "c:\Users\Robertson\Desktop\Personal Projects\pytextrpg\screenDisplay.py", line 26, in showTitleScreen
    background.display()
  File "c:\Users\Robertson\Desktop\Personal Projects\pytextrpg\Banner.py", line 19, in display
    surface = self.textObject.render(self.text, True, textWhite)
pygame.error: Text has zero width
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pygame.quit()` doesn't exit program - it only quit/close `pygame` - which means it removes `pygame`'s elements from memory.

But after you close pygame it still executes `pygame.display.update()` which makes problem.

So you would need `exit()` or `sys.exit()` after `pygame.quit()` to exit program at once.

```
 if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
     pygame.quit() 
     exit() 
     #sys.exit()
```

Or you should leave `while` loop - using rather `globalvars.gameIsDone = True` instead of `done = True` and then use `pygame.quit()` - similar to @9000 answer.

```
while not globalvars.gameIsDone:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # pylint: disable=no-member 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            globalvars.gameIsDone = True

            # pylint: enable=no-member
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `pygame.quit()` in your event loop. Note how you do a `display.update` right after it. Quit as the last thing *after* you exited the loop.

```py
pygame.init()

done = False
while not done and ...:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      done = True
      break # Other events became irrelevant.
  pygame.display.update()
  clock.tick(30)

# Now that we're done:
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still getting the same error. I did change done to globalvars.gameIsDone, but I had to.

Comment: Are you doing any drawing _after_ `pygame.quit()`? That drawing is the problem.

Comment: Is it the last thing that runs? I wouldn't know.